# Saving data in Code Composer

Tags: software, data, ti-ccstudio

I have a circular buffer in my code ([TI 28027](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tms320f28027.pdf)) saving around 500 data points. Is there a way to easily save this data to a text file in Code Composer 4? Right now I am just using watch window, stopping the code and using copy/paste but I need to manually scroll through the whole buffer first so it loads all the values.

Is there a way to do it through GEL scripts?

Does upgrading to CCS v5 help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CCS 5 (and probably in v4 too) you have a "Memory Browser" option under "View" menu. From that view you can save/load memory from your target, setting the start address, data-type and length of your data.
The output will be a binary file, but you can easily make a script to convert it to text (if needed)

This way you'll still need to pause the target. But you'll not need to scrool through the whole buffer.

Answer (score 0):

In Code Composer 3.3 on a 2812 I used to just use `printf`. It would send it over the JTAG and print the values to the console within Code Composer. I then copied out of the console into a text file for processing.

The support is defiantly still there in v5.x for at least the MSP430 according to the [TI Wiki](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Printf_support_for_MSP430_CCSTUDIO_compiler). I don't have it installed at the moment so I can't check to see if it's available for C2000 processors. But just look through the options for `printf` support and C I/O support.